# coldfusion : ws-securty X.509 / SOAP encrypt

Tags: web-services, encryption, soap, coldfusion, x509

I am coldfusion programmer with no JAVA knowledge experience.

Im working with a small project to getting some information from a webservice. We are using Coldfusion server 9.

The SSL Certificate / Keystore for both server has been setup and able to talk with each other.

However, for the SOAP content, we need signing and encrypting by using **WS-security - X.509** certificate.

Here is my cfm code :

```
<cfhttp
    url     = "[HTTPS URL]?wsdl"
    method  ="post"
    result  ="httpResponse" 
    charset ="utf-8">

    <cfhttpparam
        type="header"
        name="accept-encoding"
        value="no-compression"
    />
    <cfhttpparam
        type="xml"
        value="#trim( soapBody )#"
    />
</cfhttp>
```

below is the error message :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            X509Token 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            InitiatorToken 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            RecipientToken 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            SignedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
            Body not SIGNED 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            EncryptedParts: 
            {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
            Body not ENCRYPTED
            </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below is the sample SOAP code given from vendor :

1) SOAP content before encrypt :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:soap="http://soap.ipr.tfp.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <soap:create>
      <arg0>
        <attribute_1>abc</attribute_1>
        <attribute_2></attribute_2>
        <attribute_3>abc123</attribute_3>
      </arg0>
   </soap:create>
</soapenv:Body>
```

2) Sample SOAP content after encrypt :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-A1F720DE139A1F1A4013443711179924">MIIBqDCCARECBFARU1swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQdGVzdGNs
        aWVuddhwDz3irKnXKJK5hjLnxYygMBNAH8w=
      </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
        <wsu:Created>2012-08-07T20:25:17.950Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2012-08-07T20:30:17.950Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="EK-A1F720DE139A1F1A4013443711180615">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"></xenc:EncryptionMethod>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">DNmvc0YlN1g329Z1BMjGRj4zcz4=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue>ED3EwEOKHYr+Jdc5WtOs6DF3r7E33uRokAnuyjX/PxSQcINrYTrjOdJpN6IJvhuZrmu1I9578575685Z2mtjT/XmI9CQohLl6XmzpSdHwf70tTrsKDmpDt8HM4XPPs=</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
          <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-3"></xenc:DataReference>
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
      </xenc:EncryptedKey>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-2">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap">
            </ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1">
          </ds:SignatureMethod>
          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse soap"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">
            </ds:DigestMethod>
            <ds:DigestValue>e779ZcX0K3nc9W+Y4lzyw7KR04c=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#Id-4919785">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""></ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
            <ds:DigestValue>HHHpB67969I7BEUc=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>06t2b5COp/70OcIv4HFwO4gKILZntbleryqGNtuRMOfUbtOJU9etyetryertyxRu4LVZH7o5I=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-A1F720DE139A1F1A4013443711179852">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-A1F720DE139A1F1A4013443711179883">
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">mouSxMr4bYmR+cnkJWMyR1ymRe8=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-206789689ty-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-4919785">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"></xenc:EncryptionMethod>
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
          <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-A1F720DE13896795">
          </wsse:Reference>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:CipherValue>9Qpzj1y6EoyT9IRJZv+MF2OjxDwOY354643563456pnBD2OY7qZqb3knYLE+r3c/2fgxRpjrcKkMTYUUXQvw5467547567p354636+dd+y16OSAwicS6pyqb7eVwP33563565AfcGq0qnWsFNNJ3WX3PEO7JeKPI
        </xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below are the JAVA file provided by the Vendor.

**Client.java**

```
    package com.tfp.ipr.soap;
/**
* Please modify this class to meet your needs
* This class is not complete
*/
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
* This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.4.8 2012-07-24T10:21:51.038-05:00
* Generated source version: 2.4.8
*
*/
public final class Client {
    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://soap.ipr.tfp.com/", "WsiprService");
    private Client() {
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
        URL wsdlURL = WsiprService.WSDL_LOCATION;
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) {
            File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
            try {
                if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                    wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
                } else {
                    wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        WsiprService ss = new WsiprService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        Helpme port = ss.getWsiprPort();
        if ("validate".equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Invoking validate...");
            java.lang.String _validate_arg0 = args[2];
            com.tfp.ipr.soap.ResultDetail _validate__return = port.validate(_validate_arg0);
            print(_validate__return);
//System.out.println("validate.result="
// + _validate__return.getInstitutionDetail().getAccountNo());
        }

        else if ("create".equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Invoking create...");
            com.tfp.ipr.soap.CreationRequest _create_arg0 = new com.tfp.ipr.soap.CreationRequest();
            _create_arg0.setAttribute_1(args[5]);
            _create_arg0.setAttribute_2(args[6]);
            _create_arg0.setAttribute_3(args[3]);
            com.tfp.ipr.soap.ResultDetail _create__return = port.create(_create_arg0);
            print(_create__return);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void print(com.tfp.ipr.soap.ResultDetail r) {
        System.out.println("\n\n getInstitutionDetail_A: " + r.getInstitutionDetail().getInstitutionDetail_A());
        System.out.println(" getInstitutionDetail_B: "     + r.getInstitutionDetail().getInstitutionDetail_B());
        System.out.println(" getInstitutionDetail_C: "     + r.getInstitutionDetail().getInstitutionDetail_C());

        List l = r.getExceptionDetails().getExceptionList();
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            ExceptionDetail exceptionDetail = (ExceptionDetail)l.get(i);
            System.out.println(" Exception code: "    + exceptionDetail.getCode());
            System.out.println(" Exception Message: " + exceptionDetail.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Is anyone here can give me some guide or show me how i can implement above JAVA file into coldfusion, or how i can reverse engineer above JAVA file into CFM scipt?

Here is some research im found, not sure it that help for my issue :

1. [Using WS Security for SOAP Requests in ColdFusion](http://onlineanthony.blogspot.sg/2010/05/using-ws-security-for-soap-in.html)
2. [Java Web services: Axis2 WS-Security signing and encryption](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Java-Web-services-Axis2-WS-Security-encryption/50709)

Your help is much appreciate.

Comment: After several days and nights research, here is my finding :
There is a java tools call wss4j : https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/index.html where we can used to get the certificate / private and public key / encrypt and decrypt via Java. However, i do not found much resource how to implement with Coldfusion. Anyone used this tools before? Maybe can give me some guidance then?

Comment: Here is a post Im found interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611866/how-to-digitally-sign-a-soap-request-body-in-coldfusion . Since im not Java developer, i need some time to study how it work, perhaps anyone can give me a direction then. 

I hope coldfusion next version will implement WS-security feature.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this.... but here is code sample on how to do it. You build the Soap message manually and pass it to the function.
On the soap:body set <soap:body Id="Body">

```
function signXML (string xml_doc) {

var keystoreType = "JKS";
var keystorePass = "password";
var privateKeyAlias = "certalias";
var privateKeyPass = "password";
var certificateAlias = "certalias";
var KeyStorePath = ExpandPath("./yourKeystore.jks");

//Initialize xml security
// this need becuase Init has sepecial meaning in ColdFusion
XMLSecurityInit = createObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init");
// initialize if needed
if (!XMLSecurityInit.isInitialized()) {
    // find static method named "init" with no parameters
    method = XMLSecurityInit.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("init", []);
    // invoke it via reflection
    method.invoke(XMLSecurityInit, javacast("null", ""));
}

// Prepare for XML Parsing
dbFactory = CreateObject("java", "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory").newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbFactory.setValidating(true);
dbFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);

dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
dBuilder.setErrorHandler(CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.IgnoreAllErrorHandler").init());

// Parse the XML string to a Document
ByteArrayInputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream").init(xml_doc.getBytes());
doc = dBuilder.parse(ByteArrayInputStream);


// Get the Kestore. 
var ks = createObject("java", "java.security.KeyStore").getInstance("JKS");
var fileInputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(KeyStorePath);
ks.load(fileInputStream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
fileInputStream.close();

// Get private key and certificate
privateKey = ks.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPass.toCharArray());
x509Cert = ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias);

nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:Header");
headerElement = nodes.item(0);

body_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:Body");
bodyElement = body_nodes.item(0);

// Must define the ID attribute... can be anything... like foo or Id.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043668/getelementbyid-return-null-for-xml-document-in-java 
bodyElement.setIdAttribute("Id",true);

ElementProxy = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy");
ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig##", "");

soapsec = doc.createElementNS("", "SOAP-SEC:Signature");
soapsec.setAttributeNS("", "mustUnderstand", "1");
soapsec.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:SOAP-SEC",
            "http://www.schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12");

// Create an instance of the Transforms class
Transforms = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms");
Transforms.init(doc);
Transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);

// Create an instance of the XMLSignature class
XMLSignature = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature");
sig = XMLSignature.init(doc, "", XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);

soapsec.appendChild(sig.getElement());
headerElement.appendChild(soapsec);

Constants = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants");
sig.addDocument("##Body", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
cert = ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias);

data = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.keys.content.X509Data").init(doc);
data.addIssuerSerial(cert.getIssuerDN().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());

// Get KeyInfo from the XMLSignature and add X509Data to it
info = sig.getKeyInfo();
info.add(data);


// Sign the document
sig.sign(privateKey);

// Output the signed document to a ByteArrayOutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
XMLUtils = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils");
XMLUtils.outputDOM(doc, ByteArrayOutputStream);

// Optional: Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to a byte array if needed

signedMessage = ByteArrayOutputStream.toString();

return signedMessage;
```

}