# getElementById return null for xml document in java

Tags: java, xml, security, w3c

I am generating Document from string xml.

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc =  dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

I want to digitally sign xml request, I am using javax.xml library. Inorder to generate references, I need to pass uri of element that i neeed to digitally sign. Code i am using to generate reference is this :

```
Reference ref = fac.newReference(id, fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null), transformList, null, null);
```

Inside above function, I am getting error **resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID**. When i went inside the function *newReference*. Its calling

```
Element e = doc.getElementById(idValue);
```

*doc.getElementById(idValue)* is returning null. I wrote one test case to test **getElementById**

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><request> <myxml id=\"122\" ></myxml></request>";
String cleanXml = xmlString.replaceAll("\\r", "").replaceAll("\\n", "");
Document doc = convertXmlStringToDoc(cleanXml);
Element e = doc.getElementById("122");
System.out.println(e);
```

this is also showing null. Any idea, what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you parse xmlString to Document is right. The document contains the elements. But the attribute "id" in your String is not `ID`(doesn't matter case sensitive) of Document element. The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) of `Document.getElementById(String elementId)` said:

> Returns the Element that has an ID attribute with the given value. If no such element exists, this returns null . ... The DOM implementation is expected to use the attribute Attr.isId to determine if an attribute is of type ID. **Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or "id" are not of type ID unless so defined.**

There should be another DTD file to define which attribute is `ID` in this xml. [Here](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/DTD/Datatypes/ID.aspx) is an example, in that example, the `ID` is `artistID`.

So the right way you reach an element is like this:

```
        Element element = doc.getElementById("122"); // null
        //System.out.println(element.getNodeValue());
        NodeList e = doc.getElementsByTagName("myxml");
        NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = e.item(0).getAttributes();
        String value = namedNodeMap.getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(value); // 122
```

In your case, "id" is not a special element, it's just a simple attribute to contain information.